# Python Syntax Error Line 17

Tags: python

I've been working on a simple piece of code for my class, I've tried running it several times, and even my teacher isn't sure why it's not working. I'm currently getting syntax errors starting on line 17. Any help is welcome. :)

```
00000001 import random
00000002 
00000003 def main():
00000004     print("Intro message.")
00000005 
00000006     play_again = "Y"
00000007     
00000008     while play_again == "Y" or play_again == "y":
00000009         play_game()
00000010     
00000011     play_again = input("Do you want to play again:")
00000012     
00000013     
00000014 def play_game():
00000015     computer_choice = get_computer_choice()
00000016     player_choice = get_player_choice()
00000017     if computer_choice = 1:
00000018         print("Computer has chosen rock.")
00000019     elif computer_choice = 2:
00000020         print("Computer has chosen paper.")
00000021     else computer_choice = 3:
00000022         print("Computer has chosen scissors.")
00000023         winner = determine_the_winner(computer_choice,player_choice)
00000024         return winner
00000025         
00000026 def computer_choice():
00000027     choice = random.randint(1,3)
00000028     return choice
00000029     
00000030 def get_player_choice():
00000031     choice = input("enter 1,2, or 3")
00000032     while choice not = 1,2,3
00000033     print("error message")
00000034     choice = input("enter 1,2, or 3")
00000035     return choice    
00000036     
00000037 def determine_the_winner(computer_choice, player_choice):
00000038     if computer_choice==player_choice:
00000039         print("Result is a tie.")
00000040     elif computer_choice == 1 and player_choice == 3 or computer_choice ==2 and player_choice =1 or computer_choice ==3 and player_choice ==2:
00000041         print("You win.")
00000042             
00000043 
00000044 main()
```

Comment: I am not expert in python but single `=` doesn't have to be `==`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `==` for comparison not `=`.

`=` is for creating variables, as you have used.

For example, `if computer_choice = 1` should be `if computer_choice == 1`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Um, then if it's valid why did you downvote me? Also, this is definitely the cause of the syntax error. Your answer simply says what OP should do but that isn't the question. I don't think you understand the definition of syntax

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems. As Haidro mentioned, you are using `=` (assignment), where you should be using `==` (equality check) but you also have further problems.

Lets start with this:

```
while choice not = 1,2,3
```

That is in your `get_player_choice()` method. This line is not valid Python syntax, you probably want:

```
while choice not in ['1','2','3']:
```

(you should also indent the loop correctly).

In your `play_game` method at this line `computer_choice = get_computer_choice()`, you are calling a method `get_computer_choice`, where your method is actually called `computer_choice()`.

Further down in the same method you are calling `player_choice = get_player_choice()`, but this method is defined *after* you have defined `play_game`.

In addition, you are only checking the winner and returning the result if the computer selects 3. You need to move this line `winner = determine_the_winner(computer_choice,player_choice)` in addition to the return statement outside of the else condition - in other words, you need to reduce the indent of the line.

Comment: Hi Burhan, I'll upvote if you add a short reference to stack traces to your answer.  I bet my trousers that the OP had a stack trace leading to the source of error that you have anyway correctly identified...

Comment: @Berhuan You would get a SyntaxError using:- if computer_choice = 1: tested on Python 3.2.2 to be sure. Not to say that your suggestions are incorrect in any way.

Comment: I'm splitting hairs here but for the `while` loop, maybe having a string/char comparison might be easier instead of a list of chars? I mean `while choice not in "1,2,3"` might be more readable and slightly lighter?

Comment: @mogambo no, because then `,` would be valid input.